# c++ pragma omp segmentation fault (data race?) with arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, openmp, pragma

I used #pragma directives to parallelize my program. Without it, everything works fine.

Unfortunately, I use complex arrays which I have to declare globally because they are used in several functions within the parallelization. As far as I understand, technically this doesn't make a difference since they are stored globally anyway.

However, the problematic array(s) are used privately. From what I understood from other discussions, I have to assign memory to the arrays before the parallelization starts to ensure that the program reserves the memory correctly for every thread. Within the threads I then assign memory again. The size (matrixsize) does not change.

But even if I set num_threads(1) for testing the data (the array "degree") in the thread becomes corrupted eventually.

In an earlier version I declared the arrays within the threads and didn't use any functions. Everything worked fine too, but this is getting too messy now.

I tried to reduce the code. Hope it's understandable. I use gcc to compile it.

Sorry, I can't figure out the problem. I would be thankful for some advise.

best,
Mathias

```
#include <omp.h>
int matrixsize=200;
vector<int> degree;
vector<list<int> >adjacency;
vector<vector<bool> >admatrix;
vector<vector<float> > geopos;

\\[...]

void netgen();
void runanalyses();

\\[...]

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

\\[...]

adjacency.assign(matrixsize,list<int>());
admatrix.assign(matrixsize, vector<bool>(matrixsize, 0));
degree.assign(matrixsize,0);
geopos.assign(matrixsize,vector<float> (dim,0));

#pragma omp parallel for shared(degdist,ADC,ADCnorm,ACC,ACCnorm,its,matrixsize) private(adjacency,admatrix,degree,geopos) num_threads(1)
for (int a=0;a<its;a++)
{
    adjacency.assign(matrixsize,list<int>());
    admatrix.assign(matrixsize, vector<bool>(matrixsize, 0));
    degree.assign(matrixsize,0);
    geopos.assign(matrixsize,vector<float> (dim,0));

    netgen();
    runanalyses();

} // for parallelization

\\[...]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, I use complex arrays which I have to declare globally because they are used in several functions within the parallelization. As far as I understand, technically this doesn't make a difference since they are stored globally anyway.

You really should not do that! Modifying global data structures within parallel regions makes it very difficult to reason about data races. Instead, define proper inerfaces, e.g. passing vectors by (const) reference. For example you can safely operate on a `const std::vector&` in a parallel region.

Once you got rid of global state, and still encounter issues, feel free to ask a proper followup question, but make sure to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read that page very carefully) as well as a description of the specific error you are getting and your attempts to debug it.

Comment: Thanks Zulan! I'll look into it but may indeed have a follow-up question later.